# What will trigger an Entity Framework IQueryable query, in a helper class that inherits List<T>?

Tags: c#, pagination, linq-to-entities, ienumerable, iqueryable

I took this from [Nerd Dinner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/nerddinner/implement-efficient-data-paging) and elsewhere,

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T> {

    public int PageIndex  { get; private set; }
    public int PageSize   { get; private set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public PaginatedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize) {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        TotalCount = source.Count();
        TotalPages = (int) Math.Ceiling(TotalCount / (double)PageSize);

        this.AddRange(source.Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage {
        get {
            return (PageIndex > 0);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage {
        get {
            return (PageIndex+1 < TotalPages);
        }
    }
}
```

What is causing the IQueryable deferred query to run?  Is it because AddRange accepts IEnumerable?  AddRange itself returns void.

Comment: How are you sure it runs somewhere in the code you copied rather than somewhere else, when a client code enumerates over it?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I only know because I looked at the code on the link above.  It had removed the .ToList() method and used the Helper class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is causing the IQueryable deferred query to run?

Internally, [`List<T>.AddRange`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs.html#e569d850a66a1771) enumerates the `IEnumerable`, which causes the query to execute.

If you want to defer that, you'd have to override `AddRange` *and most all other `List<T>` members* to execute the query, *then* pass through to the base implementation.

I don't see the benefit of deferring the query.

### EDIT

I totally missed the `Count` call. That will execute a *similar* query (basically the raw query wrapped in a `COUNT(*)` outer query) which might be a concern as well. If the query is very complex and takes a long time to execute a count, this could be a source of performance issues as well.

Comment: When it "enumerates," which part of the code referenced actually causes the query to run?  AddRange calls Insert.  Is it the using...while at the bottom of the Insert method that causes the query to run?  Or is it when ICollection is first run?

Comment: @johnny It is executed when `GetEnumerator` is called in `InsertRange`.

Comment: Also, the `Count` call.

Comment: @usr great catch - I totally missed that.